Why does a command in my Bash-script return 0 even when it fails? Python, Whisper, ffmpeg
I have a bash script that executes whisper on all sound files in a directory. Whisper uses ffmpeg to decode sound files to a format it can handle. One of the files in the directory was corrupt and caused ffmpeg to fail. The first time I executed my script it returned 1 when it hit that file but when I try to reproduce the error it always returns 0.
Here is the log from the first run when 1 was returned:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/whisper/audio.py", line 48, in load_audio
    .run(cmd=["ffmpeg", "-nostdin"], capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/ffmpeg/_run.py", line 325, in run
    raise Error('ffmpeg', out, err)
ffmpeg._run.Error: ffmpeg error (see stderr output for detail)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/bin/whisper", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
             ^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/whisper/transcribe.py", line 437, in cli
    result = transcribe(model, audio_path, temperature=temperature, **args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/whisper/transcribe.py", line 121, in transcribe
    mel = log_mel_spectrogram(audio, padding=N_SAMPLES)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/whisper/audio.py", line 130, in log_mel_spectrogram
    audio = load_audio(audio)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/whisper/audio.py", line 51, in load_audio
    raise RuntimeError(f"Failed to load audio: {e.stderr.decode()}") from e
RuntimeError: Failed to load audio: ffmpeg version 4.4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --cc=/usr/bin/clang --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-audiotoolbox --disable-indev=jack --disable-libjack --disable-libopencore-amrnb --disable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-libxcb --disable-libxcb-shm --disable-libxcb-xfixes --enable-opencl --disable-outdev=xv --enable-sdl2 --disable-securetransport --enable-videotoolbox --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --enable-lzma --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-zlib --enable-libaom --enable-libsvtav1 --arch=x86_64 --enable-x86asm --enable-gpl --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
/soundfile1.opus: Invalid data found when processing input


exit: 1 //this is my own output

and here is an example of when it returns 0 despite the input file is corrupt:
% whisper soundfile1.opus

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/whisper/audio.py", line 58, in load_audio
    out = run(cmd, capture_output=True, check=True).stdout
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 571, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ffmpeg', '-nostdin', '-threads', '0', '-i', 'soundfile1.opus', '-f', 's16le', '-ac', '1', '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le', '-ar', '16000', '-']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/whisper/transcribe.py", line 597, in cli
    result = transcribe(model, audio_path, temperature=temperature, **args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/whisper/transcribe.py", line 133, in transcribe
    mel = log_mel_spectrogram(audio, model.dims.n_mels, padding=N_SAMPLES)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/whisper/audio.py", line 140, in log_mel_spectrogram
    audio = load_audio(audio)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/whisper/audio.py", line 60, in load_audio
    raise RuntimeError(f"Failed to load audio: {e.stderr.decode()}") from e
RuntimeError: Failed to load audio: ffmpeg version 4.4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --cc=/usr/bin/clang --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-audiotoolbox --disable-indev=jack --disable-libjack --disable-libopencore-amrnb --disable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-libxcb --disable-libxcb-shm --disable-libxcb-xfixes --enable-opencl --disable-outdev=xv --enable-sdl2 --disable-securetransport --enable-videotoolbox --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --enable-lzma --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-zlib --enable-libaom --enable-libsvtav1 --arch=x86_64 --enable-x86asm --enable-gpl --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
soundfile1.opus: Invalid data found when processing input

Skipping soundfile1.opus due to RuntimeError: Failed to load audio: ffmpeg version 4.4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --cc=/usr/bin/clang --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-audiotoolbox --disable-indev=jack --disable-libjack --disable-libopencore-amrnb --disable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-libxcb --disable-libxcb-shm --disable-libxcb-xfixes --enable-opencl --disable-outdev=xv --enable-sdl2 --disable-securetransport --enable-videotoolbox --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --enable-lzma --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-zlib --enable-libaom --enable-libsvtav1 --arch=x86_64 --enable-x86asm --enable-gpl --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
soundfile1.opus: Invalid data found when processing input

% echo $?
0

When I try to reproduce the behaviour I have both tried to execute the script as well as just running the actual line of code from the command prompt. The actual script looks like this:
if whisper "$file" >> "${directory}/../${transdir}/${name}.txt"; then
    whispersuccess=$?
    echo "exit code $whispersuccess"
else
    whispersuccess=$?
    echo "exit code: $whispersuccess"

I want it to return ¬0 when something like this happens. How do I achieve this?

You seem to be saying that whisper itself is inconsistent about whether it terminates with a failure status when the input file is bad.  In that case, that's primarily an issue with whisper.

Certainly the shell snippet at the end of the question does not exit with a failure status that depends on the success of the whisper command within.  It doesn't exit at all, except by reaching the end of the script, which produces a success status.  If you want to abort as soon as you notice a whisper failure then exit 1 at that point.  If you want to keep running but eventually report a failure status then you need to record the fact that one or more whisper commands failed, and use that to determine the exit status when the script eventually terminates.

What is whisper? It looks like it's a Python script, so you to find its calls to exit() to see what status it's returning. Python will only set a non-zero exit code by itself if the script crashes due to an uncaught exception.

@JohnBollinger I have realised I had two different versions of whisper, which changed this behaviour. Unfortunately, it is the old version that behaves correctly.

@JohnBollinger I am not sure I follow your second comment. The if-line executes whisper on a file, similar to cat my.txtwould do. If whisper fails, shouldn't it return a non-zero value, a value which could be branched upon (using if)?

@Barmar https://github.com/openai/whisper/

@d-b, the question posed in the title is why your script exits with status zero.  I have taken that to mean your Bash script, and that's where my second comment was targeted.  And I think my comment was at least clear in that that was the "script" to which it was directed.  Besides, whisper is not your script, and I've anyway no idea why you would be bringing us a question about the design or implementation of a third party tool such as that.

@JohnBollinger Yes it is a bash script. I want to echo the return value of whisper. Sorry, the heading of the question was ambiguous.

Can you factor out the potential for bugs in whisper and show us a problem that's unambiguously a bash issue? If whisper is returning a nonzero exit code and bash is quashing it, then you should be able to reproduce that issue with code that runs if false; then or if (exit 99); then instead of if whisper; then. Whereas if whisper is actually returning 0 when it shouldn't, that's not a problem bash can fix but is instead something you need to bring up with whisper's authors.

@d-b, inasmuch as your question seems indeed to be about the bash script part, please go back and re-read my second comment, which explains the behavior here.  In particular, that a command executed by your bash script fails does not imply that the script itself fails, or should do.

Strange: you have output syntax exit: 1 which doesn't match any of your syntaxes (you have two, which are slightly different). Also, in another case, nothing is printed at all, which is impossible with the code you posted. Are you using a different version of code? If yes, please [edit] your question and post the code you use.

@anatolyg I don't think I understand your comment. Do you think you elaborate? Thank you.

Reminder: $? stores the exit code/status from last command.
As "echo something" is likely to succeed, testing $? after your script is like checking echo command ran ok or not.
Here's a snippet to count errors, and exit with non-zero if at least one error occurred:
declare -i errors_count=0

# (/bin/true exits with code=0, /bin/false exits with code=1)
for result in true true false true false true
do 
    if bash -c $result
    then
        echo OK
    else
        echo failed
        errors_count+=1
    fi
done

if [ $errors_count -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Encountered $errors_count failures"
    exit 1
fi


Where exactly in the OP's code are they checking $? after running echo?

In second snippet, OP is running the script and printing $? after execution. and echo is the last command as shown in 3rd snippet.
If I missed something, please tell, I prefer being taught than laughed at ;)

The OP is checking $? after execution of whisper. I don't see where they're checking it after execution of their script. Indeed, I don't see anywhere they tell us how they run the script at all.

(to be explicit, whisper is a 3rd-party tool -- see https://github.com/openai/whisper/blob/main/README.md#command-line-usage)
